# Awesomium browser zoom v1.7

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

How can I zoom in/out the webControl in Awesomium v1.7? there is no webControl.zoom in v1.7... 
I am applying zoom when I start the websession, like this:

```
 myWebControl.WebSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences() { CustomCSS = "body { zoom: 200%; }" });
```

But I also want to be able to apply zoom in/out after the webcontrol has been displayed.just like we did in v1.6. Im using wpf C#.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Zoom` property and supporting API (similar to the one available in 1.6.x), will be available in the final release of version **1.7**.